# How to bind selected columns of a datatable to a datagridview

Tags: vb.net, winforms, ms-access, data-binding, datagridview

I've been searching on how to do this for an hour now but all I see are answers in C#.. I want to display data in `Datagridview1` from `tbl_scancheck`in the following order **(these are the column headers):** `Emp_No, DN_PickList, PickList_DT, DN_Thermal,Thermal_DT, TALLY`

However, `tbl_scancheck` is in this order: `DN_PickList, PickList_DT, DN_Thermal,Thermal_DT, TALLY, Emp_No`

The current tbl_scancheck order is currently being used in another datagridview so I just can't manually edit it in MS Access.

Here is my current code:

```
Dim dbprovider As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source = C:\Users\austin\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\ScanCheckSystem\ScanCheckSystem\bin\Debug\packerdb.accdb"
Dim myConnection As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection(dbprovider)
Dim da As OleDbDataAdapter
Dim ds As DataSet
Dim tables As DataTableCollection
Dim source1 As New BindingSource

Private Sub Packer_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
ds = New DataSet
    tables = ds.Tables
    da = New OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from [tbl_scancheck]", myConnection)
    da.Fill(ds, "tbl_scancheck")
    Dim view As New DataView(tables(0))
    source1.DataSource = view
    DataGridView1.DataSource = view
End Sub
```

Comment: IN the designer create columns in `DataGridView` in the order you need. Set `DataProperty` of `DataGridViewColumn` to correspondet name of column in your `DataTable`. And in the `Load` eventhandler before setting `.DataSource` set `DataGridView.AutoColumnGeneration = false`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the line where you assign the `OleDbDataAdapter` you pass in a `SELECT * FROM` SQL command -

```
da = New OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from [tbl_scancheck]", myConnection)
```

Since you know the names of the columns you want and which order you want them in, might it work if you modify the SQL to explicitly name the columns? Example -

```
da = New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT Emp_No, DN_PickList, PickList_DT, DN_Thermal,Thermal_DT, [TALLY] FROM [tbl_scancheck]", myConnection)
```

Comment: I'm currently in the middle of figuring out Fabio's answer and saw yours.. Tried it, and worked. Thanks for the simple solution.